# CSS styling not being applied to HTML elements outputted by JavaScript - XML/XSLT - ASP.NET - C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am currently working with XML/XSLT technologies for a bit of university coursework. I'm processing an **XML** file and an **XSLT** file through a **JavaScript** function and outputting the resulting **HTML** into an **ASP.NET** document.

For some reason the `HTML` is not having any styles applied to it, despite the `.aspx` document having a correct link to a **CSS** file. The other `HTML` on the `.aspx` document, which hasn't been outputted by `JavaScript`, **is** being styled correctly.

Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="master.master.cs" Inherits="master" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

        <!-- Meta -->
        <title>Site Title</title>
        <base href="http://co-web.lboro.ac.uk/colb3web/" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Head Placeholder -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </head>

    <body>

        <article id="site">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <header id="site_header" class="section">
                <section id="site_branding">
                    <h1>Site title</h1>
                </section>

                <!-- Header Navigation -->
                <nav id="site_header-navigation" class="subsection">Header navigation</nav>

            </header>

            <!-- PAGE -->
            <article id="page">

                <!-- Header -->
                <header id="page_header" class="section">Page header</header>

                <!-- Body Placeholder -->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="page_footer" class="section">Page footer</footer>

            </article>

            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer id="site_footer" class="section">

                <!-- Footer Navigation -->
                <nav id="site_footer-navigation" class="subsection">Footer navigation</nav>

            </footer>

        </article>

    </body>

</html>
```

.aspx document:

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="head" runat="server">

    <!-- Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                outputXML('content', './posts/posts.xml', './xslt/lists.xslt');
            }
        );
    </script>

</asp:content>
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="body" runat="server">

    <!-- Content -->
    <section id="content">

    </section>

</asp:content>
```

CSS file:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.section {
    padding: 10px 0em;  
}
.subsection {
    padding: 10px 1em;  
}
.area {
    padding: 5px 0.5em; 
}
.block {
    padding: 5px 0.5em; 
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
/* HTTP Request */
function loadXML(file) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // Different ActiveXObject for IE
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", file, false);
    try { xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch (e) { }; // Set responseType for IE 9+
    xhttp.send(null);
    return xhttp.responseXML;
};

/* Process & Output */
function processXML(location, xml, xsl) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document" || "ActiveXObject" in window) { // Added criteria for IE detection
        // code for IE
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = ex;
    } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById(location).appendChild(resultDocument);
    };
};

/* HTTP Request, Process & Output */
function outputXML(location, xmlFile, xslFile) {
    xml = loadXML(xmlFile);
    xsl = loadXML(xslFile);
    processXML(location, xml, xsl);
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your css?

Comment: Of course. Added now.

Comment: Is the generated `.aspx` file in the correct location/path to *see* the CSS file?

Comment: The CSS file is linked to successfully from the master page, and other elements on the page is being styled, just not the JavaScript generated HTML.

Comment: I have a feeling that the mark up generated might be malformed. Could you try running it through http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input - The "*" selector will target all elements - so if the css file is included, then it must be invalid/malformed html.

Comment: Just ran it through and it is valid, 0 errors... Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What is `outputXML()` doing? Is it emitting the markup inline, or is it appending the markup to some element?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have added the JavaScript file to the question. It is appending the mark-up as a child of the element when using browsers other than IE, is this the problem?

Comment: I've just tested it on IE and it styles the elements as expected, so I think it's reasonable to presume appending as a child was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Any suggestions for an alternative to appending child? I cannot use innerHTML as it is a document fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById(location).appendChild(resultDocument);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = resultDocument;
```

> transformToFragment will only produce HTML DOM objects if the owner document is itself an HTMLDocument, or if the output method of the stylesheet is HTML

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations#transformToFragment

Comment: This is what is then outputted to the page: `[object DocumentFragment]` which is why I used appendChild.

"transformToFragment will only produce HTML DOM objects if the owner document is itself an HTMLDocument, or if the output method of the stylesheet is HTML"... does this mean the file cannot be a `.aspx` file?

Comment: I just changed the output method of the XSLT files to HTML and problem solved! Thank you very much